# why MySql 8.0.17 Select query performance is slower than Mysql 5.7.26?

Tags: mysql, database-administration

We have very basic query like

```
select * from Some_Table
```

which used to work fine in Mysql 5.7 . And same data in Mysql 8. 0 is taking some time double the time( around 2 million data). We have upgraded from 5.7 to 8.x and seeing the performance degrade.  Also we tried changing the values for below system variables in my.cnf file but the issue still persists.

```
sort_buffer_size 
read_buffer_size 
read_rnd_buffer_size
myisam_sort_buffer_size
max_allowed_packet 
wait_timeout
interactive_timeout
connect_timeout
```

Any help will be great , how to make 8.x faster than or equal to 5.7x

Comment: After upgrade is it running on the same hardware? Same OS? With the same settings? Same engine?

Comment: only os is different , os is now sles 12 sp4 , upgraded from sles 11 sp4 .

Comment: If the os is different, have you restored sysctl settings? There are many of them affecting disk and network performance, and defaults are usually are not sufficient for databases.

Comment: I do not thing it will impact as with same OS we tried , Mysql 5.7 performance is better than 8.X

Comment: What ENGINE is being used for the table?  Is there any change in the network or client?  2M rows is a _lot_; the network delays are significant.

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this as I'm having the same issues.

Comment: No luck , we revered back to 5.7.x for now

Comment: We have the same problem MySQL 8 has a performance drop of 50% for us :-/  ... we logged all queries from one day and re-imported this dump on the same OS, same hardware, same engine, ... but one with MySQL 5.5 and the other with MySQL 8.

Comment: Same here. Got a high end server, thought I will be happy. The only changes in software was the mysql version (5.5 before, now 8.0). More than 30 % slower database. Unbelievable. - Downgrade instructions at https://askubuntu.com/a/792580/238253

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an unsolved bug!

> I'd like to confirm that I have the same problem with MySQL 8.0.21 on my Windows developer machine (64 GB RAM, Ryzen 3900, NVE SSD) where a count of a simple table with ~ 70.000 data sets takes 22 seconds. Adding WHERE id > 0 as suggested above reduces the query time to 0.2 seconds. So there is definitely a bug in MySQL 8. Testing the same table on a much slower windows machine (Surface Pro 3) with Maria 10 DB or any online Host with MySQL 5.7 also gives instant results.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97709

Here with potential patch: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=100966

However, my Mysql 8.0.23 has still slow speed issues.

The suggested temporary "fix" for the bug is to change your MySQL query (if applicable) to use `id > 0`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable 
WHERE id > 0
```

Last comment in the [mysql bug thread](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97709) is:

> We have encountered the same issue, after some extensive test we found that setting the variable [innodb_flush_method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_method) to FSYNC. The performance improves dramatically.

I have checked my DB using `SHOW VARIABLES` and found `innodb_flush_method` with value `fsync`, so this is definitely not the fix for the bug.

```
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit 1
innodb_flush_method fsync
innodb_flush_neighbors 0
innodb_flush_sync ON
innodb_flushing_avg_loops 30
```